# Почему такой код не отработает?

Tags: golang

Есть такой код:

```
package main


import (
"fmt"
"time"
)

func main() {
  ch := make(chan bool)
  var counter int
  for i:=0; i < 100; i++ {
    go func() {
      ch<-true
      counter++
      <-ch
    }()
  }
  time.Sleep(5*time.Second)
  fmt.Println(counter)
}
```

**Почему счётчик не увеличится?**
**Почему каналы в теории нельзя использовать, как мьютексы?**

Comment: Потому что все горутины будут висеть на строке `ch<-true` и ждать, пока не появится кто-то, кто соизволит из канала прочитать. Добавьте перед sleep чтение из буфера (в главной рутине), чтобы разблокировать остальные горутины.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ch := make(chan bool)` создает НЕбуферизированный канал, то есть емкость канала 0. обычно каналы работают синхронно - каждая из сторон ждёт, когда другая сможет получить или передать сообщение. Но буферизованный канал работает асинхронно — получение или отправка сообщения не заставляют стороны останавливаться. 
другими словами, пока не будет читателя из канала, `ch<-true` будет зависать.

если изменить емкость канала на 1, то проблема исчезнет. 
измените на `ch := make(chan bool, 1)`

https://play.golang.org/p/vKoeSInFIzA

Comment: Спасибо, вопрос был именно в том, почему горутина не хочет записывать в канал. Если добавить буфер, тогда появится datarace.